# Rewriting the simplified google algorithm in linear algebra form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations, page-rank

I have the expression for the rank ($x_{i}$) of a page $i$ in an internet with $n$ sites, each site contains $n_{i}$ links to other sites and is linked to by the pages $L_{i}\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$. The expression is:

$$x_{i}=\sum_{j\in L_{i}}\frac{x_{j}}{n_{j}}\tag{1}$$

We can express this in matrix form as:

$$x_{i}=\sum_{j\in L_{i}}\frac{x_{j}}{n_{j}}\implies x_{i}-\sum_{j\in L_{i}}\frac{x_{j}}{n_{j}}=0$$

And therefore we can write the system of linear equations as: $\mathbf{A}\vec{x}=\vec{0}$, with:

$$A_{ij}=\begin{cases}1 & i=j \\ -\frac{1}{n_{j}} & j\in L_{i} \\ 0 & j \notin L_{i} \cup \{i\}\end{cases}$$

I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to write the components of the matrix which doesn't involve a conditional expression?
2. Can we show that there always $\exists \vec{x}\mid \vec{x}\neq \vec{0}$?

---

EDIT: I have realised that by the Rank-nullity Theorem we can satisfy question 2 by determining that:

$$\operatorname{rank}{\mathbf{A}}\lt n$$

Thus proving that:

$$\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(\ker(\mathbf{A}))\geq1$$

And therefore that there exist $1$ or more non-trivial solutions to $\mathbf{A}\vec{x}=\vec{0}$.

Answer (score 0):

(1) I am not aware of a better way to rewrite the matrix entries.

(2) The matrix $A$ is a stochastic matrix: Let $e=(1,\dots, 1)^T$ be the columns vector filled with ones. Then
$$
A^Te=0.
$$
Thus $A$ has not full rank, and there must be non-zero vectors such that 
$$
Ax=0.
$$
In order to prove that one can choose $x$ to be component-wise non-negative, you have to look into  [Perron Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem)